# Can you use Azure cloud hosting services as a mail server?

Tags: azure, mail

Can Azure cloud hosting services be used as a mail server? I don't see anything in the Azure marketplace that correlates to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you can but due to long standing abuse seen using these networks many cloud service providers apply restrictions on sending emails from their cloud services unless you can make a specific business case to them in which case they will release the restriction for your account. I tried to do this with Azure and found the process to authorize it was too long and complicated and very poorly documented so I went across to an alternate cloud provider for my email hosting and had a VPS set up with them and after a single web form submission and 24 hours later it was approved and outbound emails from that server where allowed.